# How do I use BorderLayout with Netbeans Matisse

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-platform, matisse

I decided to change the layout on my component in Netbeans GUI builder (aka Matisse).

[image]

Now it has completely screwed up my panel. I want to add a main panel to the center (ie default), and then add other components to the left or the right, however in Netbeans I don't see any option in the builder to add something NORTH, SOUTH etc.

Comment: can you change its by hand in file ?

Comment: netbeans matisse doesnt let you change this in code

Comment: Yet another case of 'the tail wagging the dog'.  Stop being your IDEs 'bitch'.

Comment: agree. GUI builder is great for the short term, to throw something together. But when things get serious... you gotta hand-code the GUI code.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, that is the kind of stuff I hear people say when I tell them I code in Java.

Comment: @oliverwatkins, "when things get serious... you gotta hand-code the GUI code" is simply not true...

Comment: I'm going to write a blog about the many exceptionally robust GUIs I've written exclusively with Matisse...

Comment: @ryvantage *'..you gotta hand-code the GUI code" is simply not true.'  Agree strongly with that.  I've seen some masterful GUIs created with Matisse.  The 'objections' I have to GUI designers are 1) They are often used by people that don't yet understand the layouts. 2) They make the code non-portable (e.g. "don't edit this in Eclipse!" type crap).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, yes. Both good points.

Comment: GUI Builders are fine, but they only provide a static representation. What happens when the GUI changes depending on user, or state? At that point i need always need to abandon the GUI builder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to the desired component and right-click in properties then layout and then select the desired direction.

[image]

Comment: Image is currently broken, Great, Now the accepted answer is no longer useful !!

Comment: Found it, for anyone who is stuck like I was,
From properties -> layout -> direction (Center, North, south, ...)

Comment: @Argento the image is not broken, but i'll add text information too